# How to disable warning produced by DOMDocument::schemaValidate() when the schema is invalid?

Tags: php, validation, schema, domdocument, libxml2

To avoid PHP warnings in schema validation process, one can use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);`, and `libxml_get_errors()[0] -> message;` to "manually" administrate eventual validation error messages. This works when it is the XML that does not match a schema, but a warning is still being fired when the schema itself is invalid.

`libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` already captures the error message in the returned array of errors, the warning seems redundant to me, any way to bypass/disable this particular warning?

I work in strict mode, so I stop the execution when a warning fires, and log the error in a database, the problem is that the PHP warning is too vague, so I want to bypass it to report the libxml error in a separate logging system, and see the detailed error afterwards.

Is this warning a correct behavior? any chance it is a bug?

---

The PHP code:

```
<?php
    $DD = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-1');
    $DD -> loadXML('<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><a></a>');
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // NO LIBXML WARNINGS
    $DD -> schemaValidate(__DIR__ . '/schema.xsd'); // Vague WARNING
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();

    if (isset($errors[0])) {
        echo $errors[0] -> message; // Libxml detailed message
    }
?>
```

---

The PHP warning:

> DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Invalid Schema

---

The libxml detailed error message:

> Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}complexType': The content
>   is not valid. Expected is (annotation?, (simpleContent |
>   complexContent | ((group | all | choice | sequence)?, ((attribute |
>   attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?))))

---

The invalid schema (schema.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema
    targetNamespace="http://www.lala.com/la"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:la="http://www.lala.com/la"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
>
    <xs:element name="foo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:element ref="bar"/><!-- lacking <sequence> parent -->
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would expect to happen. As per the documentation, DOMDocument::schemaValidate validates a document based on a schema. Therefore, if the schema itself is invalid, it can't be used to validate a document.

You could try and prefixing the command with @ - see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php. This should suppress the warning allowing your code to continue. If that doesn't work, you could try temporarily disabling error reporting using error_reporting(0) (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) before calling DOMDocument::schemaValidate. Then, restore the previous setting which would have been returned when you called error_reporting(0).

Comment: The problem is that it will disable any warning. Ideal solution would be to check if the schema is valid as a prior step, but looks like there is not any function to check a schema before using it, the only solution seems to be to create that function with some kind of bullet proof hack implementing the @ operator that you suggest, to detect precisely if a schema is valid or not, without confusing that aspect with other kind of libxml errors or PHP warnings.